# I want to plot a line and scatter graph of the following dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I want to plot a graph of the following dataframe. I found very little information about plotting scatter graph for dataframe with more than one column and with proper labeling of all rows and all columns.

```
id  VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4    VAR5    VAR6    VAR7
A   -7.820508635    4.162811012 7.882904258 -0.2387979  -1.65208602 5.423443603 0.795919218
B   4.451872938 4.451872938 4.451872938 4.451872938 5.223271289 4.451872938 4.451872938
C   2.054657373 15.61346543 4.02425573  3.564059023 1.362852568 10.54007004 -0.310328384
D   -8.18383731 36.19338103 -0.871780578    1.110804933 0.100712338 1.85553191  2.035597797
E   28.66910089 5.78170381  3.64203503  -0.985332565    -0.737553812    -1.317628533    3.957412529
F   -86.68625074    53.76371348 -12.23370566    -71.06690958    -50.90228788    82.0763054  115.9051108
G   3.283603399 3.283603399 3.283603399 3.283603399 3.233161507 3.283603399 3.283603399
H   2.486224726 2.486224726 2.486224726 2.486224726 2.486271838 2.486224726 2.486224726
I   2.005977875 6.346998811 13.25051632 1.507138669 -0.677090408    6.396818693 5.142696619
J   4.665795513 9.877903133 4.457264304 3.293945877 0.527442939 1.425336142 6.201919544
K   0   0   0   0   21.59506088 0   0
L   0.046009792 -1.465259749    27.92458641 0.678544482 -1.924224493    9.039317136 5.293844806
M   0   0   0   0   59.79910714 0   0
N   4.895828747 4.895828747 4.895828747 4.895828747 31.63622676 4.895828747 4.895828747
    O   10.12289317 10.12289317 10.12289317 10.12289317 -16.99283013    10.12289317 10.12289317
    P   -5.356344923    20.79762384 2.541882605 -1.719624366    1.349900946 0.994027528 6.786979543
    Q   5.709233691 15.20123769 0.026043141 0.545894575 2.437443516 -3.003799771    6.763437647
    R   4.425459095 8.70475642  24.47906189 2.047957343 1.280841422 9.087579892 12.35633041
```

Comment: What does `df.plot` give you and what's wrong with it?

Comment: I could able to plot the line graph. But it is not showing the 'id' labels (A,B,....). I am unable to find which label corrosponding to which coordinates


df = pd.read_csv("K:\\data.csv")
df.plot(linestyle='-', marker='o')
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

maybe `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix` would help you.

```
import pandas.plotting
pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha = 0.3, figsize = (14,8), diagonal = 'kde')
```

Comment: You are right but this is not what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestion. It guided me well to my direction. I got the solution which i was looking for

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.plot(figsize=(8,6), xticks=range(0, 8)).legend(title='id', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

It did the trick for me

Answer (score -1):

Humans understand only 3 dimentions. You can do 3d scatter and you won't be able to show 7 columns at once. Basically it's hard to visualise more than 2 dimentions in a scatter plot.

You can choose two best informative columns to do a scatter plot 
or to reduce dimentionality from 7 to 2-3.

Comment: You can also add color and size of scatter as 4th and 5th dimention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about line graph is it possible to plot all the rows from A to N vs all variables in the same graph with multiple lines

Comment: It's sure possible. Did you read my comment below your question?

Comment: How it's possible to visualize more than 3 dimentions on scatter plot?

Comment: Ofc it's possible to plot a line plot by:
df.plot()
plt.show()

Comment: @PiotrKubica : I could able to plot the line graph. But it is not showing the 'id' labels (A,B,....) on x-axis.